# Doesn't work loading.jsx in next js 13.4.5

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, frontend

Doesn't work loading components in next js 13.4.5

layout.jsx

```
"use client";
import React, { Suspense } from "react";
import { ThemeProvider, createTheme } from "@mui/material/styles";
import CssBaseline from "@mui/material/CssBaseline";
import Loading from "./loading";

const darkTheme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    mode: "dark",
  },
});

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={darkTheme}>
      <CssBaseline />
      <html lang="en">
        <title>auth</title>
        <body>
          <header></header>
          <Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
            <main>{children}</main>
          </Suspense>
          <footer></footer>
        </body>
      </html>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

loading.jsx

```
"use client";
import React from "react";
import CircularProgress from "@mui/material/CircularProgress";

function Loading() {
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        display: "flex",
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
        height: "100vh",
      }}
    >
      <CircularProgress />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Loading;
```

I tried asking chatGPT but it didn't give me a definitive answer

I want to get the page loaded, not the page where css styles are not yet connected

Answer (score 0):

To show loading in the fallback of Suspense, I recommend using the

`React.lazy(() => import())` component.

Suspense does not detect when data is fetched inside an Effect or event handler.

Link : [React DOCS](https://react.dev/reference/react/Suspense)